# Deploy NodeJS app to GCP AppEngine with customize start command

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

Here is my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start:develop": "env-cmd -f env/.env.develop react-scripts start",
    "start:stage": "env-cmd -f env/.env.stage react-scripts start",
    ...
}
```

env folder structure

```
env
├─ .env.develop (env=develop)
├─ .env.stage   (env=stage)
```

When run on local (MacOS)

- "yarn start" runs NodeJS app on local with default "env" = local (which is defined in other file)
- "yarn start:develop" runs NodeJS app on local with "env" = develop

But now when I want to deploy this to GCP AppEngine, it's always deploy with "start" command (equivalent to "yarn start" on local)

How can I deploy "yarn start:develop" to AppEngine without declaring more environment variables in app.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/deploying-web-service) about what happens when you deploy your program,

> Node.js modules are installed in the cloud as listed in your package.json and package-lock.json files and your service is started by using **`npm start`**.

I interpret the above to mean your project on the cloud is always run with `start` script and GAE will not/does not know how to use another script.

A possible workaround could be to deploy your app using a different version name e.g. `dev` i.e. you have

1. Your `default` version with `"start": "react-scripts start"`
2. `dev` version with `"start": "env-cmd -f env/.env.develop react-scripts start"`

Both of your versions use only the `start` script but they do different things